# How to add header in a row of a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using **bootstrap v3.0.2**.

the following is my html, css code for a table

```
<table class="table data-table table-bordered no-bottom-margin usage-detail-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Used</th>
            <th>Deleted</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>{{'update-profile.detail-usage.personal.files' | translate}}</th>
            <td>{{usageDetails.personalDiskUsage | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</td>
            <td>{{usageDetails.personalDeletedDiskUsage | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</td>
            <td>
                <b>{{usageDetails.totalPersonalUsage | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>{{'update-profile.detail-usage.shared.files' | translate}}</th>
            <td>{{usageDetails.sharedDiskUsage | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</td>
            <td>{{usageDetails.sharedDeletedDiskUsage | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</td>
            <td>
                <b>{{usageDetails.totalDeleted | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <td>
                <b>{{usageDetails.totalUsed | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>{{usageDetails.totalDeleted | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>{{spaceUsed | commaSeparatedNumber}} bytes
                        <br>({{spaceUsed | sizeText}})</br>
                    </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table want to give the first column element the same look as the table header. But `<th>` tag is not working. How to add row headers here?

Comment: The 'bootstrap' styles will likely be checking for thead>tr>th - so you'll have to copy those to use tbody>tr>th.  So far you've only copied `align-right`, you'll also have to copy the background-image/etc as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/0x6gogv6/

Seems to be working as per your need.

The only minor connection done was:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Used</th>
        <th>Deleted</th>
        <th>Total</th>
   </tr> <!-- This was tr in you code -->
</thead>
```

Comment: fixed the tag. still it's not working. elements are bold now, but background is not look alike horizontal headers at the top.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7m8u3k i can see this.

can you please show the screenshot that you are expecting by manually doing using developer tools?

Comment: something is missing since the above code and using the bootstrap 3.0.2 gives me the output without any color.

can you please check the CSS properties that are getting applied to the horizontal headers (probably background or background-color)? I have tried it on fiddle and even on my machine but i cannot get the background color anyhow.

Comment: I don't find any properties like background or background-color. It's coming from thead

Comment: what are the properties coming from thead? this not probably coming from some other library or custom css.

http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.2/docs/css/#tables-example

boostrap doesn't give any color to the head as per the docs